# react native metro server

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, apk

I have an error with React Native apk it works fine in android studio with different emulator versions but when I copy the apk from (android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug) to my real device it doesn't work

[image]

Comment: do you have index.android.bundle file ?

Comment: if not thn you can create it by (run it in project root dir): react-native bundle --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --dev false --reset-cache --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/

Answer (score 1):

If you use the latest React Native App, The first time you must run

```
react-native start
```

then you must run

```
react-native run-android
```

And if still works you must rerun again, I don't know the latest react-native has bugs like that.

And make sure you in same network.

And make sure too the port in the dev setting in your mobile is correct.

Comment: Thank you, I just try to run 'cd android && gradlew assembleRelease' then test the released apk in my device and it works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this mistake use another port than the default 8081.

```
npx react-native run-android --port 8089
```